# Python: easiest and bulletproof way to read and write a small file

Tags: python, file

I have a script which will (among other things):

- read the first line of a file (which is a hex int) to store it in a variable
- read and increment the second line of that same file (dec int)

So, what's the simplest way without having to pull my hair because of the position etc.

Alternatively, should I organize my file differently?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: When you say "read and increment the second line of the same file" does that include writing it back to the same file?  Is your file a text file or a binary file?  If it's a text file could you show a sample of the first two lines of the data?  Please show what code you have written to solve this problem.

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski
 It's any file you want me to use (currently a text file). The file could for instance contain "0x2227AB" on line 1 and "13" on line 2.

I will need to read 0x2227AB and store it in a variable.
Then read 13 and store it in a variable.
Then replace 13 with 14 (and increment it the next time I open the file) and close the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves your problem:

```
with open(SourceFile, 'r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()

print "Your data at line 1" + data[0]
data[1] = "New line to insert instead of the 2nd line\n"

with open(SourceFile, 'w') as file:
    file.writelines( data )
```

Comment: I wasn't clear but by _increment the second line of that same file_, I meant I hade to write a new value in lieu of the one that has just been read.

Comment: so you want to insert a line right after the 2nd line?

Comment: I want to **replace** the second line.

Comment: @Nicolas If you knew you wanted to do all those specific things those would have been important details to be clearly stated in your question.

Comment: @James Adkison Everything I needed was stated in the question. I needed to read to lines and increment the second one. I don't know what "other things" you wanted me to mention.

Comment: @Nicolas The person providing this answer wasn't clear on what you wanted and you provided specific details (i.e., "other things") in the above comments to make your question more clear. There are also comments on your question requesting clarification. FYI, I was just trying to be helpful to point out that your question could have been made more clear and could have been edited to make it more clear once others showed they didn't understand what you were asking.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't think the best way would be to re-write the first line as well but I was probably wrong.

I tried *fileinput()* (with *inplace=1*, you can *print* to your file), I made a mess.

So, largely inspired from @mid 's solution, here is my code:
    #!/usr/bin/env Python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
nom = "chambre"

with open(nom + ".txt", 'r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()

remote = int(data[0], 16)
code = int(data[1])
data[1] = str(code + 1)

print hex(remote)
print code

with open(nom + ".txt", 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import io  

firstLine = 0x10  
secondLine = 0x20  

print ("create file")  
file = open('test.txt', 'w')  
file.write(hex(firstLine) + '\n')  
file.write(hex(secondLine) + '\n')  
file.flush()  
file.close()  
file2 = open('test.txt', 'r')  
print ("create file done")  

print ("read file")  
first = file2.readline()  
second = file2.readline()  
firstLineOut = int(first,16)  
print ('First: ', hex(firstLineOut))  
secondLineOut = int(second,16)  
print ('Second: ', hex(secondLineOut))  
file2.close()  

print ("update file")  
secondLineOut += 1  
print ('Second New: ', hex(secondLineOut))  
file2 = open('test.txt', 'w')  
file2.write(hex(firstLineOut) + '\n')  
file2.write(hex(secondLineOut) + '\n')  
file2.flush()  
file2.close()  
print ('done')
```